# How can I get the VERSION_NAME of an application in a method included in a library common to several applications?

Tags: android, build.gradle, buildconfig

I have developed a library to share code that is common to two applications. One of the shared methods is intended to display the VERSION_NAME of the application. This VERSION_NAME is set in the `build.gradle` file of each application. When I Use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME` in the code of the library method, it returns the version name of the library. How can I reference the variable set into the application gradle file?

Comment: You may need to post your code. Right now, it sounds like you should not have a library, but I think the issue is how you worded the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will not be able to use `BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME`, because when your library is compiled the consuming application's `BuildConfig` won't exist.

Instead, you will need to use the package manager to query the current application's version name like so:

```
public String getCurrentApplicationVersionName(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    return info.versionName;
}
```